# Percentile rank without 0

Tags: python, pandas, rank, percentile

I am trying to calculate percentile score but instead of having 0-100, I need the scores to be 1-100.

Currently, I am using this method which is 0-100. How can I make it 1-100 instead?

```
df['Percentile_score'] = df.Score.rank(pct = True)*100,0
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you just looking to re-scale the value so that it falls in the range of 1-100 instead of 0-100? This sounds like you just need to do `f.Score.rank(pct = True)*99 + 1`

Comment: Hey i manage to find the answer using qcut and to define the bins manually with a list

Answer (score 0):

i manage to find something that works using qcut

```
li = list(range(1,101))

df['Percentile_score']= pd.qcut(df['Score'], q=100, labels = li)
```